# MassTransit Respond going to same queue and causing loop

Tags: c#, windows-services, servicebus, masstransit

We're currently switching out `NServiceBus` for `MassTransit` and I'm having a little difficulty with the request/response pattern.

In `NServiceBus`, I'm able to do reply in the `Handler` and it goes back to the client that sent it.

In `MassTransit`, it appears as though the response is being sent back to the queue that it was consumed from, thus creating a loop...

Weird thing, if I'm creating the Bus using InMemory, and both client and consumer on the same machine, I do not have the issue.

I am expecting my client to catch the response, but instead my `Consumer` picks it up, which is also odd, since it's not setup to receive that message type...

Am I missing something in the client's Request setup?

***Client:***

```
....
IRequestClient<IWorklistRequest, IWorklistResponse> client = CreateRequestClient(busControl, WorklistEndpointUri);

Console.Write("Sending Request");

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    IWorklistRequest request = new WorklistRequest
    {
        CurrentDateFrom = new DateTime(2016, 11, 07)
    };

    var response = await client.Request(request);

    Console.WriteLine("Worklist Items retrieved: {0}", response.ExamItemList.Length);

}).Wait();
....



static IRequestClient<IWorklistRequest, IWorklistResponse> CreateRequestClient(IBusControl busControl, string endpointAddress)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating Request client...");

    var serviceAddress = new Uri(endpointAddress);
    IRequestClient<IWorklistRequest, IWorklistResponse> client =
    busControl.CreateRequestClient<IWorklistRequest, IWorklistResponse>(serviceAddress, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    return client;
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IWorklistRequest> context)
    {
        _log.InfoFormat("Received Worklist Request with Id: {0}", context.RequestId);


        try
        {
            var result = _provider.GetAllWorklistsByStartDate(context.Message.CurrentDateFrom);

            IWorklistResponse response = new WorklistResponse
            {
                ExamItemList = result.ToArray()
            };

            // the below is sending the response right back to the original queue and is getting picked up again by this same consumer
            context.Respond(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Info(ex.Message);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RabbitMQ, and you are using the request client, you should not see this behavior.

There is a sample that demonstrates how to use the request client on the MassTransit GitHub repository: https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse

The code above appears to be correct, and the `Respond()` call should use the response address from the request message, which is a direct endpoint send to the temporary bus address.

There is pretty extensive unit test coverage around this area, and the sample above was updated and verified with the latest version of MassTransit. You might consider deleting/recreating your RabbitMQ virtual host and running your application from scratch (start the response service first, so that the endpoints are setup).

Comment: Yeah, that's the sample I was actually working with to guide me with the implementation... I'll see if recreating the RabbitMq host might fix that, it is the existing one I was using with NServiceBus.

Comment: Deleted and recreated the RabbitMQ host and the problem still persists. It's saying it cannot find the response endpoint. When both client and bus are on the same machine this isn't an issue.

Comment: Are both services connecting to RabbitMQ using the same address? Or is one of them using a different host address? For instance, one using local host and the other using a network name? Also, don't use the guest account remotely with RabbitMQ.

Comment: Yes, receiver is using `localhost` and the client is using the IP. I'm not using the guest account.

Comment: Both need to use the IP, you can't mix the addresses. Local host can't be resolved on the other end.

Comment: Dude - thank you so much. I knew it had to be something minor.